# Angular unit test a prop is never undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I don't understand why on earth
this simple test doesn't work.

```
BannerComponent should not have welcome message after construction
Expected 'welcome' to be undefined.
```

// Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'iwdf-banner',
  template: `
    <p>
      {{me}}
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {
  me: string;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.me = 'welcome';
  }
}
```

// Test

```
describe('BannerComponent', () => {
  let component: BannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BannerComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should not have welcome message after construction', () => {
    expect(component.me).toBeUndefined();
  });

  it('should welcome logged in user after Angular calls ngOnInit', () => {
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.me).toContain('welcome');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `TestBed.createComponent` will call the constructor of the component, but not any lifecycle hooks.

The `OnInit` lifecycle hook will be called the first time you call `fixture.detectChanges()`, which you do before every test. So that's why `me` has the value `welcome` instead of being undefined.

You can fix this by removing `fixture.detectChanges()` from the `beforeEach`, and moving it to individual tests that need it (which will be all but that one failing test). You do not need to call `ngOnInit` manually on that last test once you replace the line with `fixture.detectChanges()`.

Calling `ngOnInit` manually might be useful if you want to test your component without the angular testbed - you would then have to take care of the dependencies and lifecycles yourself, which I don't suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Well, TestBed does run all the nescessary lifecycle hooks on detect changes. So it is to be expected that the variable is defined. Don't use `fixture.detectChanges()`. That one runs the hook.